# FindBugs can't throw NoSuchElementException

Tags: findbugs, nosuchelementexception

I have following code snippet:

```
@Override
public Message next() {
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    // return statement
}
```

However, findbugs says that there is BAD_PRACTICE:

> It: Iterator next() method can't throw NoSuchElementException
>   (IT_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT) 
>   This class implements the java.util.Iterator
>   interface.  However, its next() method is not capable of throwing
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException.  The next() method should be changed
>   so it throws NoSuchElementException if is called when there are no
>   more elements to return.

I do not understand how to fix the code to pass findbugs check. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it really the `NoSuchElementException` from `java.util`? Or have you maybe imported a different one by accident?

Comment: Yes, it's java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Then we'd need to see your complete class, or better the simplest class with which you can reproduce the behavior. It could be a shortcoming of the detector, or some part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `mvn clean` on the project. I have the same issue because SpotBugs uses previously compiled class without changes. So `mvn clean` or manually deleted this class helps me.

Update. Also, you probably don't need to invoke `hasNext()` from `next()` method.